# Motherboard beeps when disconnecting sata drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, sata, hotswapping

I'm trying to setup a sata enclosure so that I may use hot swappable drives for my Microsoft SBS 2011. I have set it up with AHCI so that I could supposedly take advantage of hot swapping sata.

I can safely stop/disconnect my external sata drives using a program called [usbsafelyremove](http://safelyremove.com/). But when I physically turn off the drive, so that I can unplug it, my motherboard starts beeping constantly. I can't seem to find any information on why it is beeping constantly.

The only thing that stops the beeping is if I plug a drive back in (which I don't always want to do). Is there a away around this beeping? Can I turn it off? Is there something wrong with what I am trying to do?

Thank you for the help!

**Update**

I have a Asus Z8PE-D18 motherboard. I'm trying to find out if it supports hot swapping, but am having a lot of trouble tracking down where I can figure that out, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all SATA controllers support hot-swapping.  This is not simply a matter of having a hot-swapping enclosure & switching to AHCI mode.  More than likely, the motherboard is beeping because (despite usbsafelyremove's claim) it did not expect a hardware failure.  (yes, losing power to the motherboard looks like a hardware failure)  Even if Windows is OK with having the device removed from the system, the controller may not be happy.

All that aside, you might be better off looking for specific drivers pertaining to your motherboard/SATA controller which may offer a better interface for removing drives while the system is running.  Frequently, there's a simple RAID utility that can perform that task for you without having to turn to some random 3rd party app.  Additionally, it is probably a good idea to look to the manufacturer of the motherboard to see if your motherboard does support hot-swapping.

Comment: Good information, looking into things now, check my update if you would like. :)

Comment: I just happened to download & peek at the manual for that mobo... according to ASUS, it does support hot-swapping.  That being said... make sure you install & use the manufacturer's drivers/utils.